# Подскажите (сайт)

Tags: html, css

Обращаюсь к вам, потому что только вы даёте ясный ответ на вопросы. В общем хочется делать сайты. Да не просто делать их, да и еще заработать на них. Знания есть в html,css и чучуть php. И не большой опыт в создании сайта. Вот только не знаю с чего начать, в голове каша,в наушниках Радиохед. Большая проблема в выборе тематики. Посоветуйте, наставьте на путь истинный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, то что вам не обойтись без дальнейшего обучения - думаю, что и так понятно. Если не учитывать статически сайты-визитки и т.д., то без знаний и опыта разработок, используя по крайней мере PHP, MySQL (или бругой базы), JavaScript и прочих опасностей, создать полноценный сайт увы не получится. Но и это еще пол беды. Одной из самых ценных вещей в этой области, да и самой дорогооплачиваемой, является "**креатив**". Мало написать грамотно сайт, надо чтоб он еще был интересен определенному кругу людей. А интересные идеи, как вы уже сами поняли, приходят очень туго )) Цитата: "*Вот только не знаю с чего начать, в голове каша*". Поэтому включайте фантазию, нарабатывайте навыки в создании динамических сайтов, следите за новинками в этой области, анализируйте успешные ресурсы в сети, черпая от них лучшее и будет вам счастье. Только заработав свой первый миллион, не забудьте пригласить меня на банкет ))